# Making a video-chat app in js without nodejs

Tags: javascript, web, server, video-streaming

I have a server (cPanel) in GoDaddy. And I want to create a video chat app without NodeJS.
Tutorials on the web use NodeJS. Can't I just run it on GoDaddy cPanel Linux hosting servers?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use some open-source projects.

https://jitsi.org/projects/

Step by step set up : https://jitsi.github.io/handbook/docs/devops-guide/devops-guide-start

Just set up the `jitsi Videobridge` and `jitsi-meet` in 30 min and you are ready to go.

> Make sure to open the required port of the firewall.